# Error when adding new columns in PostgreSQL with Prisma

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, prisma

my name is lucas and I'm a front-end developer and I'm venturing into node and prisma.
I created my api project with prisma and postgres running on docker, until then everything was working, but I decided to add new columns in my sql table, since then my api does not respond.

This error appears when I try to do a login POST:
`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

I added the new columns in `schema.prisma` and the command `yarn prisma migrate dev`

everything went well, except that the api stopped responding to login and registration attempts

Comment: The ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error suggests that your API can't establish a connection with the PostgreSQL database running on Docker. Can you check if you are able to connect to the database?

Comment: I can start the container with the command: ´docker-compose up -d´, and also connect the database via pgadmin over port 5432, however, the api does not work

Comment: Is your code open source? If yes, if you could share it, I can have a look and try to reproduce.